# App requires latest version of ARCore. Google Play Services for AR says my device isn't compatible with this version

Tags: android

What steps do I need to take when I have troubles trying to use an app I created and try to run it on the latest Samsung Tab A 10.1? I tried to start the app, the message displayed is :

```
This application requires the latest version of ARCore
```

So I tapped the continue button. I was taken to Google Play. The title says "Google Play Services for AR". Then below that it says:

```
Your device isn't compatible with this version
```

Does anyone have a solution, please?

Comment: A10 not listed in https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices#android_play

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check whether the device you are using has the ARCore support:

It was indeed an easy experience in terms of building and running the app on the IOS device, iPhone 10. There were no complications in activating the ARkit in the devices since they were built in like the documentation mentioned. It was particularly gruesome in building the AR app on an Android device. As per the documentation the Android devices such as Samsung Galaxy A70S is compatible with ARCore.

Firstly the app simply crashed on installing into the device
As a part of the workaround, I looked for installing, "Google Play Services for AR" on my play store which simply didn't show up
I directly tried to install the app "Google Play Services for AR" through google but it failed with the message, the app is not compatible with my device. 
I did a trial and error with installing the "Google Play Services for AR" apk directly from https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/arcore/,  specifically https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/arcore/arcore-1-13-19100710-release/google-play-services-for-ar-1-13-191007106-android-apk-download/ to my Android device to enable ARCore which supported 64-bit processor
The app was however still crashing due to the 403 forbidden IP error on persisting the data
The issue got resolved on adding my public IP to azure rules